# ui-sref not generating the href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm not sure what is the mistake I'm doing here but the href is not generating. I have configured as per ui-router example but when I put the ui-sref in the ng-repeat its not generating the URL and also when I type the URL manually also its not working.

Even when I tied to set the value like `data-ng-click="widget.open({widgetId: 1})` nothing happens.

Here is my code snippet.

Config:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '/templates/home/home.html'
                })
                .state('widget', {
                    // With abstract set to true, that means this state can not be explicitly activated.
                    // It can only be implicitly activated by activating one of its children.
                    abstract: true,
                    // This abstract state will prepend '/widgets' onto the urls of all its children.
                    url: '/widget',
                    // Loading a template from a file. This is also a top level state,
                    // so this template file will be loaded and then inserted into the ui-view
                    // within index.html.
                    templateUrl: '/templates/widgets/index.html'
                })
                .state('widget.open', {
                    url: '/{widgetId:[\w+$]}', //matches  [a-zA-Z_0-9]
                    templateUrl: '/templates/widgets/index.html'
                })
                .state('widget.create', {
                    url: '/{type:[a-zA-Z]}', // We can test enum list also
                    templateUrl: '/templates/widgets/index.html'
                })
                .state('mashup', {
                    // With abstract set to true, that means this state can not be explicitly activated.
                    // It can only be implicitly activated by activating one of its children.
                    abstract: true,
                    // This abstract state will prepend '/mashups' onto the urls of all its children.
                    url: '/mashup',
                    // Loading a template from a file. This is also a top level state,
                    // so this template file will be loaded and then inserted into the ui-view
                    // within index.html.
                    templateUrl: '/templates/mashups/index.html'
                })
                .state('mashup.open', {
                    url: '/{mashupId:[\w+$]}', //matches  [a-zA-Z_0-9]
                    templateUrl: '/templates/mashups/index.html'
                })
                .state('mashup.create', {
                    url: '/{templateType:[a-zA-Z]}', // We can test enum list also
                    templateUrl: '/templates/mashups/index.html'
                });
        }])
```

Template:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default widget-list">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">My Widgets ({{widgets.length}})</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body hp-content">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
          <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="w in widgets">
            <td class="hp-type">Icon</td>
            <td>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <a data-ui-sref="widget.open({widgetId: w.id })">{{::w.name}}</a>    
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                  {{::w.sourceId}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                  {{::w.communityId}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="hp-actions">{{::w.access}}</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel footer</div>
    </div>
```

[image: Update: compiled template]
Could someone please point the mistake what I'm doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap the `widget.id` in curly braces:

```
data-ui-sref="widget.open({widgetId: {{widget.id}} })
```

Use:

```
data-ui-sref="widget.open({widgetId: widget.id })">
```

Comment: I tried this as well but didn't work, see commented code in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a naming issue. You are in a repeater that is `widget in widgets`, so when you do `widget.open`, I think its looking for a open function in the the widget object of the repeater and not the sub route 'widget.open'.

Comment: I have changed the variable name as well but didn't work.

Comment: I can't tell what you renamed in the commented out code. what did you put in the `data-ng-repeat`?

Comment: I have updated my code. The ```data-ng-repeat``` will have array of objects ```[{id: 1233, name: 'xyz', ....}]```.

Comment: Hmm okay, so just to be clear is the repeater working at all? Is it actually iterating through your array of objects and displaying everything? Or is nothing at all working? I assume this is so, but I just want to cover all bases before moving forward.

Comment: Yes, the ng-repeat is working as intended. I have rewritten the same code using the ng-route and its working now. I have now removed the ui-router.